# How to change size of INImage in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I have this code:

```
extension IntentHandler: SelectEmojiIntentHandling {
  func provideEmojiOptionsCollection(
    for intent: SelectEmojiIntent,
    with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<EmojiINO>?, Error?) -> Void
  ) {
    
      var imageUrl = ...//gets local file
      
      var theImage = INImage(url: imageUrl, width: 500, height: 500)
      let finalThing = EmojiINO(identifier: item, display: item, subtitle: "Some Image Subtitle", image: theImage)
      emojiItems.append(finalThing)
    }
    completion(INObjectCollection(items: emojiItems), nil)
  }
}
```

The code above successfully displays an image, but it ignores whatever dimension I give it for size.  How do I change the size of an image on the edit widget screen?

[image]